# Exclude regex assertion from result?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract a part of text (book reference) from products description in a large database

Example :

```
books A 41.14 (products -> cat1 -> (1990-2000))
```

I only need the `A 41.14`

I have tried this in PHP (always followed by parentheses)

```
books(.*)(?=\s\(.*\))
```

but it does not capture as expected, i need to exclude assertion, is it possible?

Comment: Is "books A 41.14" always at the start of a line? and is the format always the same: "books"+"uppercase letter"+ "number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the product code which interests you can never include the open parenthesis character then you could simply use this pattern:

```
books\s+([^(]+)\s+\(
```

If the open parenthesis character can appear in the product code then your task is trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\K` in your regex to exclude the previous matches and also use lookaheads to check what's following should be `\s*(` (*ie, zero or more spaces followed by a `(` symbol*)

```
books\s*\K.*?(?=\s*\()
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vI5yV4/1)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = "books A 41.14 (products -> cat1 -> (1990-2000))";
$regex = '~books\s*\K.*?(?=\s*\()~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> A 41.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
preg_match( '/books\s?([\w]+\s?[\d|\.]+).*/i', "books A 41.14 (products -> cat1 -> (1990-2000))", $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Hope it helps,

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If wou always have one letter before float you can use.

```
(\w (\d+)\.(\d+))
```